# How do pointers increase execution speed?

Tags: pointers

How does using a pointer in a program increase the execution speed?
When I use a pointer to access a variable while running the program first it has to go to the pointer's address to find the address of the variable and then go to the variable to use it(that's what I know).
It is obvious that using a variable is faster here.
So how does a pointer increase the speed?

Comment: Also how big is the thing that you are pointing to? do you really want to pass it by value all the time?

Comment: Where is the evidence constable?

Comment: Using a pointer does not increase execution speed.

Comment: What language are we talking about here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing a pointer to 4KB of data, is faster (and uses less memory) than copying that 4KB to pass it "by value".

You are correct that, for a simple 'integer', passing it directly is faster than passing a pointer to it & de-referencing (looking up) the pointer.

Pointers are typically used for larger data-structures than that, however.

The other use of pointers is to enable *modifiability* -- the function can modify the original data or data-structure via the pointer received, rather than just having a copy which is independent of the caller's & to which the caller would not see changes.

For example a FILE * -- a pointer to a file-handle. I/O functions take this & update internal pointers to keep track of where you are, in the file.

Comment: How about if the function needs to change the value of the passed integer?

Comment: @Ed: Isn't that covered in the last (well, now second-to-last) paragraph?

Comment: Yes, @EdHeal, I covered modifiability in the 4th paragraph - -and specifically mentioned _data_ as well as _data structures_, to cover the possibility of modifying that int via the pointer.